# CRM 2015 + Activities not related visible in social pane

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I am facing an issue where in an email activity which is not related to my account is visible in social pane.

For eg. There is Account A and Account B

And an Email activity named Email A

So in Email Activity - 'Email A' i have selected Account A in the regarding field, However this email activity is visible in social pane in both the accounts - Account A and Account B.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This doesn't happen in my lab... Can you provide a detailed step-by-step on how to reproduce the issue ? By *detailed* I mean like "click this button, type this in that field, etc. etc.". Start from the beginning assuming no pre-existing data in the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The social pane shows activities (e.g. emails) from the current account as well as child accounts.

In your case Account B would be the parent account of Account A (or at least Account A would be an ancestor of Account B), since the email shows up in the social pane.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. i did check both the accounts if they are related to each other in any way but unfortunately they are not related and still this issue is occuring. can you point out to me any other thing which could be the issue behind this

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my question posting it so that it might help others -

The email activity as explained in the example Email A had an contact mentioned in the 'CC' field of email activity.

And the Contact had its Parent Account set a 'Account B'. Hence it was visible in Account B also.